# Leafet - I need to show more markers

Tags: wordpress, leaflet

I am running leaflet.js for map on a WordPress site that is pulling locations from a Custom Post Type (Metabox.io). I have everything working, except I am only getting 10 markers on the map. There are currently 24 locations in the CPT. I have found questions here about how many markers can be on a map and I am definitetly not anywhere close to the limits I've see in answers on stackoverflow.

**Here's the code I'm using in my function:**

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    if ( is_page( 641 ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'leaflet', 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css', [], '1.5.1' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'leaflet', 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js', [], '1.5.1', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'collab_list', get_theme_file_uri( 'collaborative.js' ), ['jquery', 'leaflet'], '1.0.14', true ); 
    }   
    });
    
         function bww_collaborative_maps() {
          

   $locations = [];
        $query = new WP_Query( [
            'post_type' => 'collaborative',
        ] );
        foreach ( $query->posts as $post ) {
            $location            = rwmb_get_value( 'location', '', $post->ID );
            $location['title']   = $post->post_title;
            $location['address'] = rwmb_get_value( 'collaborative_city_and_state', '', $post->ID );
            $location['icon']    = rwmb_get_value( 'collaborative_map_icon', '', $post->ID );
            $location['url']     = $post->post_name;
            $locations[]         = $location;
        }
        wp_localize_script( 'collab_list', 'Locations', $locations );
    }
add_shortcode('collaborative_map','bww_collaborative_maps');
```

**And here is the code in my .js file:**

```
( function( document, Locations, L ) {
    // Set map center = first restaurant location.
    var center = [39.043135, -98.148637];

    // Map options.
    var options = {
        center: center,
        zoom: 4
    };

    // Initialize the map.
    var map = L.map( document.querySelector( '#collab_map' ), options );

    // Set tile layer for Open Street Map.
    var tileLayer = L.tileLayer( 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        } );
    map.addLayer( tileLayer );

    // Show marker for each location.
    Locations.forEach( function( location ) {
        // Marker options.
        var options = {
            title: location.title,
            icon: L.icon( {
                iconUrl: location.icon,
                iconSize: [30, 50]
            } )
        };
        var center = L.latLng( location.latitude, location.longitude );
        var marker = L.marker( center, options ).addTo( map );

        // Show name of the restaurant when click on the icon.
        marker.bindPopup( '<span style="font-size:.9rem;"><b>' + location.title + '</b></span><br>' + '<br/><b><a style="font-size:.7rem;" href="' + location.url + '" target="_blank">More Information</a></b>' ).openPopup();
    } );

} )( document, Locations, L );
```

Here's the live page: https://ecf.mywp.dev/collaborative-map-test/

I would be so grateful for any ideas on how to get this map showing all the markers instead of just 10. Thank you!

Comment: If you log `Locations` how many items do you get?

Comment: In your developer console, just type Locations and you will see that his length is 10...
More, it is not  related to Wordpress but javascript and leaflet

Comment: THANK YOU for answering. @dmoz provided the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress by default shows [10 posts](https://wordpress.org/support/article/settings-reading-screen/) for a query.

In your WP_Query args, `$query`, set `'posts_per_page'` to `-1` to get all posts:

```
$query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'collaborative',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
]);
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters